# Problem calculating distance between multiple objects in .Lua

Tags: lua

I'm currently working in a mod for project zomboid and i'm struggling with this calculation.

I have to calculate 2 objects. PlayerObj and ZombieObj. To create and area radius. I'm using this script:

```
function Crawl.DistanceHandler (firstObj, secondObj)

-- firstObj = PlayerObj
-- secondObj = ZombieObj

local playerPos = {x = firstObj:getX(), y = firstObj:getY()}
local zombiePos = {x = secondObj:getX(), y = secondObj:getY()}

        
        local dx = zombiePos.x - playerPos.x
        local dy = zombiePos.y - playerPos.y
        local distance = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    
    return distance 
end
```

It does calculates the distance between player and zombie correcly. But here's the catch, the zombieObj is multiple, so it return multiple distances, which is ok actually, but i need a way to use only the shortest one, ignoring the others.

if i use

```
function .....
 if distance < 20 then
  do something
 else
  do other thing
 end
```

It won't work properly because if there's an zombieObJ in a distance > 20, the else part will be trigger as well, creating an endless loop.

Is there a way i can get around this? I'm not an expert, can't figure out.

Tried almost everything i now.

Comment: Square root on the distance is not needed if all you are doing is comparing which object is closer. Saves a bunch of potentially expensive operations.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as best you can. How exactly your descriptions apply to your examples is a bit confusing (especially the second example). If you need to find the "smallest" value (or object containing a particular value) in a table you can: write a *min* function that performs a linear search of the table and returns the minimum value in it, **or** *sort* the table in ascending order and take the first element from the result.

Comment: You say "the zombieObj is multiple" -- can you can show us the objects you actually want to work with? No one is here to guess the problem you're trying to solve.